# Swift 2.0 UIImageViev как получить смену изображений из массива

Tags: swift

```
// запуск функции по селектору = "runMe0004" из таймера
var startTimer0004: NSTimer!

self.startTimer0004 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(7, target: self, selector: "runMe0004",userInfo:nil,repeats: true)

func runMe0004() {

    let imShowTir = Tir[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(tir.count)))]

    let imTir = UIImage(named: imShowTir)
    let imTirView = UIImageView(image: imTir!)   //reloadInputViews
    imTirView.frame = CGRect(x: 12, y: 20, width: 365, height: 640)
    view.addSubview(imTirView)   }

// все изображения по arc4random_uniform добросовестно грузятся из
// массива в заданноую точку и с заданным размером и аккуратненько
// друг на друга...пробовал пристроить  .reloadInputViews , но
// это не прошло... как сделать смену изображений, а не накладку = ?
```

Comment: вы каждый раз создаете новый `UIImageView`, а вам надо создать один, сохранить референс и каждый раз менять свойство`.image`

Comment: эх, если бы Вы знали какой я свежак в этом деле и еще при ком меня принимали в пионеры...ну хорошо...получается надо ставить второй таймер на image = ? @MaxMikheyenko

Comment: вещь!!!...других слов нет...да и не знаю, что разрешают выражать на этом форуме, что б не отругали...@MaxMikheyenko

Comment: тут можно принять ответ, который помог (галочка возле ответа) и можно отметить ответ как полезный (стрелка вверх возле ответа)

Comment: да все время пробовал жать на все это, но как-то не понятно...даже свой вопрос нахожу через поиск по заголовку...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить еще одну переменную типа `UIImageView`

```
var imTirView: UIImageView!
```

и использовать ее:

```
func runMe0004() {


    if(self.imTirView == nil) {
        self.imTirView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 12, y: 20, width: 365, height: 640))   //reloadInputViews
        view.addSubview(self.imTirView)
    }
    let imShowTir = Tir[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(tir.count)))]
    self.imTirView.image = UIImage(named: imShowTir)

}
```

что то типа такого. сам компилировать не пробовал, могут быть ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код при каждом входе в функцию таймера создает новый `UIImageView` и добавляет его на `view`. Это неправильно, т.к. для загрузки нового изображения нужно всего лишь поменять свойство `image` созданного ранее `UIImageView`.